# scanf able to scan multiple characters using "%c" instead of "%s", why?

Tags: c, char, scanf

this is a code that recieves an unknown number of characters from user until he enters ";" and then prints a bunch of information about the characters.
my question is why is scanning a char able to recieve an input of multiple characters, i thought a scanf of a char is for one char only and to be able to scan multiple characters i need to scan a string or an array by using "%s".

```
  Include files:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


/*=========================================================================
  Constants and definitions:
==========================================================================*/

/* put your #defines and typedefs here*/

void printGivenParamsToTheOutput( char ch, int asciiCode, int asciiCodePowTwo,
                                  int difference, int unitDigitOfDiff );

void printResults(int digitsCounter, int lettersCounter, int spacesCounter);


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  The main program. (describe what your program does here)
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main() {
    char ch = 0;
    int privNumChar=0, dif=0, lastDigDif=0, numDig=0, numLett=0, numSpac=0;
    do {
        scanf("%c", &ch); //asking for characters to analysis
        if (ch == ';') { //';' ending the program running
            break;
        }
        else {
            // difference between current number to the previous one
            dif = ch - privNumChar;
            privNumChar = ch;
            //calculating the difference last digit
            lastDigDif = dif%10;
            printGivenParamsToTheOutput(ch, ch, ch, dif, lastDigDif);
            //calculating how many times each type appeared in the message
            if (('a'<=ch && ch<='z') || ('A'<=ch && ch<='Z')) { ++numLett; }
            else if ('0'<=ch && ch<='9') { ++numDig; }
            else if (ch == ' ') { ++numSpac; }
        }
    }
    while (ch != ';');

    printResults(numDig, numLett, numSpac);
    return 0;
}

 void printGivenParamsToTheOutput (char ch, int asciiCode, int asciiCodePowTwo,
                                    int difference, int unitDigitOfDiff){
    asciiCodePowTwo = ch*ch; //calculating ascii value raising to a power
    printf( "%c%10d%10d%10d%10d\n", ch, asciiCode, asciiCodePowTwo,
            difference, unitDigitOfDiff );
}


void printResults(int digitsCounter, int lettersCounter, int spacesCounter){
    printf("Number of digits received: %d\n", digitsCounter);
    printf("Number of letters received: %d\n", lettersCounter);
    printf("Number of spaces received: %d\n", spacesCounter);
}
```

Comment: OT: Please use the [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha), [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit), and [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Comment: Also OT: Why do you pass `asciiCodePowTwo` as an argument to the `printGivenParamsToTheOutput` function? Why can't it be a local variable defined inside the function itself? Why does it even need to be a variable? Why not use `ch * ch` as the actual argument to `printf`?

Comment: As for your problem, you read only one character. *At a time*. Each iteration through the loop will read just one single character, but the loop as a whole will read multiple characters.

Comment: I suspect the confusion would be cleared up if you added a line at the end of the if/else chain like `else { fprintf(stderr, "unexpected character '%c(%x)'\n", ch, ch); }`  and you would start seeing the program processing the newlines.

Comment: Always check the return values  of scanf

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
do {
    scanf("%c", &ch); //asking for characters to analysis
    //some further code
while (ch != ';');
```

Now, you are reading characters into `ch` repeatedly until the end-sign of `;`. You are not doing it with a single `scanf` call, but it is being called repeatedly instead until an end sign of `;` being received.

Try debugging the code and see what you get into `ch` each time and then you will see that your presumption about `scanf` receiving a single `char` per call into your `%c` is being adhered to.

Answer (score 1):

"characters" in comment `scanf("%c", &ch); //asking for characters to analysis` is imprecise.

`scanf("%c", &ch);` only reads 1 character into `char ch`.

Answer (score 1):

scanf function deals with Buffer *(piece of memory where data is stored temporarily until it's processed or copied to the final destination or other buffer)* so when you are entering multiple characters like ABCD using `scanf("%c", &ch);` it would firstly put A to `ch` and put BCD in the buffer so when the code sequence get back to `scanf("%c", &ch);` again it will already have a value at buffer which is BCD so B will be stored in `ch` and so on, so basically when we are using scanf *(With characters)* to get a value like ABCD it firstly stores it to Buffer  and then put it to the variable one by one.

There are many ways to solve such problem like using fflush(stdin) but in most of time it doesn't work so we can just use getch().
you can check this for more [How to Clear Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-can-i-clear-an-input-buffer-in-c)